# What's the difference between Acfg and ALLcfg

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, notation

In computational theory, and talking about CFGs, Turing Machines, and so forth I haven't a satisfactory explanation or definition for what A*TM* means versus ALL*TM*   or the same or similar uses with CFGs, etc. Does the single A stand for any, some, one, or all instances of the class whether it's a TM, a CFG, or anything else? Conversely, E*TM* and EQ*TM* are obvious as to what they mean.

Comment: Those notations may not be fixed completely. Please edit the question to add a reference to the textbook you are using.

Comment: $ALL_{TM}$ usually means the set of turing machines which accept any input (that is, $L(M) = \Sigma^*$).